# Ribbon Control Focus on button click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control

I have a problem with the Microsoft Ribbon Control. If I have the focus in a Textbox and click a Button in the Ribbon menu, the focus still remains in the `Textbox`. And so the textbox property in my `ViewModel` does not get updated.

I searched the web but did not find a solution. I tried setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` and `Focusable` of the `Ribbon` control with no effect.

All I want is if the button is clicked the textbox looses focus.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine something like this: (assuming the ribbon's x:name is ribbon)

```
ribbon.PreviewMouseDown += handlerMethod;
public void handlerMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ribbon.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried your solution, it works if I set FocusManager.IsFocusScope to False for the Ribbon. Is this with XAML only also possible?

Comment: I don't know, I'll try and find something.